# How can I make a Python package which serves a website with Flask to work with Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have written a Python package [`hwrt`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt) (see [installation instructions](http://pythonhosted.org/hwrt/installation.html) if you want to try it) which serves a website when executed with

```
$ hwrt serve
2014-12-04 20:27:07,182 INFO  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
2014-12-04 20:27:07,183 INFO  * Restarting with reloader
```

I would like to let it run on http://www.pythonanywhere.com, but when I start it there I get

```
19:19 ~ $ hwrt serve
2014-12-04 19:19:59,282 INFO  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MartinThoma/.local/bin/hwrt", line 108, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/MartinThoma/.local/bin/hwrt", line 102, in main
    serve.main()
  File "/home/MartinThoma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hwrt/serve.py", line 95, in main
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 739, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 613, in run_simple
    test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I only found this in the documentation:

> Flask
>
> never use app.run(), it will break your webapp. Just import the
>   app into your wsgi file...

By searching for wsgi file, I found [mod_wsgi (Apache)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/). However, I don't understand how I can adjust my current minimalistic Flask application to work with that. Currently, the script behind `hwrt serve` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Start a webserver which can record the data and work as a classifier."""

import pkg_resources
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import os
import json

# hwrt modules
import hwrt
import hwrt.utils as utils


def show_results(results, n=10):
    """Show the TOP n results of a classification."""
    import nntoolkit
    classification = nntoolkit.evaluate.show_results(results, n)
    return "<pre>" + classification.replace("\n", "<br/>") + "</pre>"

# configuration
DEBUG = True

template_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('hwrt', 'templates/')

# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_path)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def show_entries():
    heartbeat = request.args.get('heartbeat', '')
    return heartbeat


@app.route('/interactive', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def interactive():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        raw_data_json = request.form['drawnJSON']
        # TODO: Check recording
        # TODO: Submit recorded json to database
        # Classify
        model_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('hwrt', 'misc/')
        model = os.path.join(model_path, "model.tar")
        print(model)
        results = utils.evaluate_model_single_recording(model, raw_data_json)
        # Show classification page
        page = show_results(results, n=10)
        page += '<a href="../interactive">back</a>'
        return page
    else:
        # Page where the user can enter a recording
        return render_template('canvas.html')


def get_json_result(results, n=10):
    s = []
    for res in results[:min(len(results), n)]:
        s.append({res['semantics']: res['probability']})
    return json.dumps(s)


@app.route('/worker', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def worker():
    # Test with
    # wget --post-data 'classify=%5B%5B%7B%22x%22%3A334%2C%22y%22%3A407%2C%22time%22%3A1417704378719%7D%5D%5D' http://127.0.0.1:5000/worker
    if request.method == 'POST':
        raw_data_json = request.form['classify']
        # TODO: Check recording
        # TODO: Submit recorded json to database
        # Classify
        model_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('hwrt', 'misc/')
        model = os.path.join(model_path, "model.tar")
        results = utils.evaluate_model_single_recording(model, raw_data_json)
        return get_json_result(results, n=10)
    else:
        # Page where the user can enter a recording
        return "Classification Worker (Version %s)" % hwrt.__version__


def get_parser():
    """Return the parser object for this script."""
    from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
                            formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    return parser


def main():
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, a not so non-sequitur answer to your question is around what mod_wsgi does to interface with your app.  A typical flask app would look something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Holy moly that tunnel was bright.. said Bit to NIC"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Unfortunately, Apache has no way to know what to do with this (though the app would run happily on its own).  In order to get the app and Apache to play nice together we're going to use something called mod_wsgi.  What Mod_WSGI does that's important to us, is that it provides a known interface (a file type called wsgi) that's going to wrap our application and initialize it so that we can serve it through Apache.

I'm going to assume you are using a python virtual environment, but if you aren't you can omit the step that deals with this in the instructions below.  If you're curious why virtual environments are so great, [feel free read about the python ecosystem](http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/).

Also - you can include an extra flag (assuming you are running wsgi as a daemon) to automatically reload the daemon whenever you `touch` or alter your wsgi file.  This is quite useful during development and debugging so I'll include is below.

Anyway, let's get started.  I'll break this down to steps below.

### Configuring Apache for mod_wsgi

1. Enable mod_wsgi in Apache:

   - `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`
2. Edit your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<yoursite>.conf`.

   ```
   <VirtualHost interface:port>
        WSGIDaemonProcess yourapp user=someUser processes=2 threads=15
        WSGIProcessGroup yourapp

        # In this case / refers to whatever relative URL path hosts flask
        WSGIScriptAlias / /absolute/path/to/yourapp.wsgi

        <Directory /path/to/your/main/py/file/ >
            # Use good judgement here when server hardening, this assumes dev env
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
            #The below enables 'auto-reload' of WSGI
            WSGIScriptReloading On
        </Directory>

        # If you want to serve static files as well and bypass flask in those cases
        Alias /relative/url/to/static/content/
        <Directory /absolute/path/to/static/root/directory/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Create your yourapp.wsgi file and put it in the appropriate place: *Be wary of file permissions!*

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import sys
   import logging

   # Activate virtual environment.
   # If you are not using venv, skip this.
   # But you really should be using it!
   activate_this = "/path/to/venv/bin/activate_this.py"
   execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

   # Handle logging 
   logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

   sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/main/py/file/")
   from YourMainPyFileName import app as application
   application.secret_key = "your_secret_key"
   ```
4. Reload Apache and troubleshoot problems.  I set this up probably every few weeks for a different project or idea I have and... I usually have to fix one thing or another when doing it from scratch.  Don't despair though!  [Flask has great documentation on this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache).

Once you've done all this you should be at a place where flask runs all on its own.  The sample flask app above is the actual code I use to verify everything works whenever I set this up.

---

**This was left here in case it's some use, but is not really directly related to the question...**

The answer here is to use x-send-file.  This takes advantage of letting Apache do what it's good at (serving static content), while at the same time first letting flask (or other python framework) do it's work first.  I do this often to let flask handle my auth layers in single page web apps and have so far been happy with the results.

Doing so requires two things:

First - Enable xsendfile on Apache2 `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile`.

Second - Alter your apache2 configuration so allow x-send-file headers:

Alter your conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<yoursite>.conf` and add...

- `XSendFile On`
- `XSendFilePath /path/to/static/directory`

*This can be entered top level within the `<Virtualhost></Virtualhost>` tags.*

Don't forget to restart Apache `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Finally - Configure your flask app to use x-send-file in your app.py file:

`app.user_x_sendfile = True`

*Note: Must be done after app initialization.  Consequently can also be passed as an initialization parameter.*

[Flask has documentation on this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.use_x_sendfile) (excerpt below):

> **use_x_sendfile**
>
> Enable this if you want to use the X-Sendfile feature. Keep in mind that the server has to support this. This only affects files sent with the send_file() method.
>
> *New in version 0.2.*
>
> *This attribute can also be configured from the config with the USE_X_SENDFILE configuration key. Defaults to False.*

Comment: Man, could not you write this up about a week back?

Comment: Some follow-up questions: (1) `yourapp` can be anything, right? (2) `/path/to/your/main/py/file/` should be something like `/home/moose/main.py`, right?

Comment: I've created [`/home/moose/hwrtapp/main.py`](http://pastebin.com/yUmaa39J), [`/home/moose/hwrt.wsgi`](http://pastebin.com/bFdaJbbY) and adjusted [`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`](http://pastebin.com/VuhiVnx8). But when I try to access http://localhost:5001 I get no response (Google Developer tools say "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"). What is wrong?

Comment: What are you looking for on port 5001?  Did you configure apache to run on a non-standard port?

Comment: Moose to answer some of your follow up: short answer is (1) Yes @moose - yourapp can be anything and (2) Yes-ish is about as far as I'm willing to go with that response... I wouldn't put it in the home folder of the root (or really, even a sudo-able user).  You do highlight on an important point though - wherever you put it... beware the permissions!  One could argue that the answer to 2 depends to a large degree on the sysadmin/devops decisions and whose patch of Nirvana you currently reside in.  Beware the permissions! :P

Comment: As a side-note: (If this is just a test/local environment you can forego a some level of paranoia in the interest of speed)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue @moose was having. Getting connection refused and couldnt even telnet localhost 5000.

Turns out theres a ports.conf file i had to add Listen 5000

Happy days.

Comment: It would be great if you can elaborate more on your answer.

Comment: Sure. I ssh into my server.
cd /etc/apache2
you'll see a file named ports.conf
So type sudo vi ports.conf

Then Shift i to switch vim into insert mode.

cursor down to the line Listen 80 (and optionally add a # at the beginning of that line to stop listening on port 80)
line below add
Listen 5000

then ESC then shift Z Z

then run these for good measure
sudo service apache2 reload and
sudo service apache2 restart